# show group header only on subsequent pages

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that has two levels of repetition and would like to have two page headers for.

The report is essentially a report of reports. ie. We have many devices we are producing reports for, each device has multiple tests. We want all the devices to be in the same overall report so the page numbers are continuous through the entire report. The first page of each device has the device information which is a fixed length and takes roughly 1/2 the page, following this device information is the test information which can take multiple pages.

What I would like to do is have an effective page header for each Device, and a different effective page header for the subsequent pages of test output.

ie.

```
-Page 1-
Device Page Header
 Device Info
Test Header
 Test Data
-Page 2-
Test Page Header
 Test Data
-Page 3-
Test Page Header
 Test Data
-Page 4-
Device Page Header
 Device Info
Test Header
 Test Data
-Page 5-
Test Page Header
 Test Data
-Page 6-
Test Page Header
 Test Data
Report Footer
```

I understand that I can Repeat Group Header on Each Page, but what I don't want is to have it show on the "first" page of that group, where it would be out of place in the middle of the page following the device info.

Is there a way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: how many detail records are on a full page?

Comment: That varies, the test data can be one record or 30. So sometimes the pages for a single device and it's tests will be 1 page, sometimes it could be 10 pages.